# Land cost data of the region Caucasus

Tags: data-request, geospatial, economics, land

I am using the R package ['prioritzr'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prioritizr/prioritizr.pdf) to identify new possible conservation areas in the lesser caucasus for different species.

One main data input to solve the problem is the average land cost per grid cell (planning unit).

So far I did not find any data about land cost in the region of the lesser caucasus.

Also trying different approaches by using the GDP in combination with population densitiy and landuse classes did not lead to a satisfying outcome. Simply by mulitplying these values led to a very high difference between min/max which resulted in a not usable dataset for the problem-solver.

Do you have any suggestions how to get land cost information about the region in the lesser caucasus or do you have other approaches how to solve the problem?

Comment: My suspicion is that comprehensive land value data derived from market transactions will be extremely hard to come by since this region is characterized by limited legal recognition of land ownership (see [here](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/inov_a_00276)).  Which data did you use for the GDP-based approach?  Something like [G-ECON](https://gecon.yale.edu/)?

Comment: GDP via https://data.worldbank.org/ , population density via Openstreetmap , landuse classes via satellite images